# throwing aurahandledexception is not sending message correctly to LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, exception

I am calling an apex controller, that has several try-catch blocks that throw exceptions depending on the error or situation, (i am also throwing outside of try catch blocks) this is an example:

```
try{
                    tipo = [
                        SELECT  id
                        FROM    Tipo_Comprobante_Movimiento_Fondo__c 
                        WHERE   Tipo__c = 'Cobranzas' AND 
                                Empresa__c = :empresaSelected AND
                                Cuenta_Contable__c = :cc
                    ];
                }catch(Exception e){
                    throw new AuraHandledException(System.Label.consulta_saldo_cliente_18);
                }
```

Here, I'm sending a label already saved in custom labels, but there are other thrown with normal strings:

```
throw new AuraHandledException('No se pudo completar el proceso');
```

For some reason, the message of the error from the LWC side, is "script thrown exception"...

[image]

this happened to me today for the first time.. I was already working with these exceptions and this never happened.

Comment: actually, my mistake. I am throwing exceptions outside of try catch blocks also

Comment: and, I checked the stacktrace of the error and it points to the catch block, so it is actually throwned inside the try catch

Comment: please provide code of apex method and js

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recollect that this is a design quirk of `AuraHandledException` and that e.g. this is needed (constructor argument probably doesn't matter):

```
AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException(System.Label.consulta_saldo_cliente_18);
e.setMessage(System.Label.consulta_saldo_cliente_18);
throw e;
```

which is not convenient so best to wrap in a method:

```
private AuraHandledException newMessageException(String message) {
    AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException(message);
    e.setMessage(message);
    return e;
}
```

so you can then conveniently:

```
throw newMessageException(System.Label.consulta_saldo_cliente_18);
```

Comment: thanks! this works, I had already done this to test aurahandledexceptions but I thought the whole point of this type of exception was to be captured by LWC and getting the messages correctly. I don't know how this happened all of the sudden